# Comparing a String to a String PHP

Tags: php

I've looked at some other answers here to get the technique for this and it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm comparing an array value returned from a payment gateway response to an existing string like so:

```
// $this->config->get('ezic_avs') returns DFJMQVXYLWZABOPUSCIG
// $this->result['avs_code'] returns X

if (strpos ($this->result['avs_code'], $this->config->get('ezic_avs')) === false):      
    // avs code doesn't match: fail
    $this->json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_avs');
endif;
```

This should not return false since `X` is found inside `DFJMQVXYLWZABOPUSCIG` but yet it does.

What exactly am I doing wrong here that would be causing this to fail?

Thanks.

Comment: The haystack comes first in the method signature. [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your arguments are backwards. strpos is $haystack, $needle

Comment: Well crap!  Thanks so much :)

Comment: No problem. Although, to be fair, I actually think danronmoon got there first.